# Switch case opearation when strings are placed (ascii values) in c

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() {
     switch(*(1+"AB" "CD"+1)){
        case 'A':printf("Pulp Fiction");
                  break;
        case 'B':printf("12 Angry Man");
                  break;
        case 'C':printf("Casabance");
                  break;
        case 'D':printf("Blood Diamond");
     }
}
```

My doubt is in switch statement why is it taking only the first letter ascii value in the string (`"AB"` `"CD"`)? (Here it is taking `'A'` ascii value and then `65+1+1` hence it is `67` ascii value of `'C'`.
What operation is going on inside ?

Can anyone explain this switch case please. Thanq

Comment: What's the motivation behind `*(1+"AB" "CD"+1)`. This is nonsense.

Answer (score 4):

This code doesn't make any sense, because the switch expression is constant.

```
*(1+"AB" "CD"+1)
```

first goes through the translation step that concatenates any adjacent string literals, so it becomes

```
*(1 + "ABCD" + 1)
```

which is equivalent to

```
*("ABCD" + 2)
```

In this context, the string literal is evaluated as a `char *` pointer to its first element. Now you increment that pointer by 2, so it points to the 3rd letter, the `C`, which is then taken by the dereference.

Answer (score 2):

That code is nonsense. Its a fancy trick, but due to how the compiler evaluates it, you can substitute

```
switch(*(1+"AB" "CD"+1)){
```

directly with

```
switch('C'){
```

which completly negates the reason for a `switch` statement entirely.

Added explaination:

```
*(anything)
```

Is evaluated as pointer to a string literal.
The compiler (thanks Mr.Oehm for pointing out that its not the preprocessor) automatically merges `"AB"` `"CD"` into `"ABCD"`
`1 + Anything + 1` is evaluated as `Anything + 2`
Finally. `"ABCD" + 2` is, to the switch statement equal to `"C"` since it points to the third char in the string literal.

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't evaluate anything here. And surely you mean `switch('C')`, no?

Comment: Yes, I've edited it about 5s ago. And yes, the preproc evaluates nothing, but it does concat the two strings together automatically, which is what I meant there.

Comment: String literal concatenation is not performed by the C preprocessor, but by the compiler.

Comment: @MOehm you're right, although there *are* sources claiming otherwise, it seems to be the typical (and more sensible) approach to let the compiler do it ... maybe just copied from my answer? I'll update mine ...

Comment: Felix Palmen I've always been under the impression the precprocessor does things like this, although, my last lesson on the topic is a while out of date. Looking at internet sources as prompted, there seem to be conflicting sources as to what does it, favored towards the compiler.

Comment: It seems that concatenation is being done by the compiler and that the preprocessor resolves string literals that are spread across several lines by escaping the new-line character with a backslash. Anyway, where exactly the concatenation happens isn't important to the OP's problem; sorry for bringing it up.

Comment: @MOehm it's not, but it's still a good hint that -- to be entirely "correct" -- one shouldn't talk about anything but the respective translation phase.

Comment: I agree its a valueable info in case something like this ever comes up. SO answers should never contain outright false information, relevant to the topic or not.

Comment: @MOehm: The way I read 5.1.1.2, it sure *sounds* like translation phase 6 (where string literals are concatenated) is done by the preprocessor, since phase 7 is where preprocessing tokens are converted into tokens, and phase 7 is where lexical and syntax analysis occurs.